# Ajustar tamaño de Windows Form a cualquier pantalla

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación dentro de C# en la cual estoy utilizando **Windows Forms**. Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que mi `Form` al momento de inicializar se adapte a la pantalla de cualquier computadora donde sera utilizada, lo utilice con la propiedad `WindowState` en `Maximized` pero se expande y tapa la barra de tareas.

Quite la propiedad de `FormBorderStyle` lo que pretendía era hacer mi propia barra para cerrar, minimizar y maximizar. Por eso quería saber como podía hacer que al iniciar la aplicación se abriera ya maximizada respetando la barra de tareas.

Mi Aplicación va así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En Visual Studio en propiedades del formulario hay una opción que se puede habilitar para indicarle en que posición mostrar el formulario cuando se inicialize la aplicación: en medio, pantalla completa o dimensiones específicas. Aquí el enlace [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: tu barra de tareas esta definida para ocultarse automaticamente? porque si no esto no deberia pasar

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, No no la tengo para ocultarse automáticamente, lo único que utilice fue la propiedad de WindowState el cual al inicializara se despliega en toda la pantalla como si presionara F11 en las paginas web.

Comment: @gbianchi Olvide decir que quite el FormBorderStyle el cual hace que no respete la barra de tareas.

Comment: Es como un detalle bastante importante no? Jajaja.

Comment: Si perdón jeje, pero lo que pretendía era hacer mi propia barra para cerrar, minimizar y maximizar. Por eso quería saber como podía hacer que al iniciar la aplicación se abriera ya maximizada respetando la barra de tareas.

Comment: Entonces aclara esa informacion en la pregunta.. y puede que la respuesta te sirva entonces

Answer (score 1):

Regresa el **WindowState** a "Normal" y en el evento que carga la ventana puedes asignar un tamaño basado en el tamaño de la pantalla.
Puedes poner también **StartPosition** en **CenterScreen**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  var bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
  this.Width = bounds.Width - 100;
  this.Height = bounds.Height - 100;
}
```

Comment: es una solucion interesante, pero el formulario ya deberia abrirse solo al tamaño maximo...

Comment: Visto la nueva informacion proporcionada por quien pregunta, puede que la respuesta le sirva. Por favor podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia el mismo problema lo solucione colocando en el vento load del form esto:

```
 this.MaximumSize = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize;
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: habrá alguna forma de abrir el formulario al tamaño de la pantalla pero que ocupe el espacio de la barra de tareas ?